# Is it possible to debug Linux core (dump) files with CLion?

Tags: linux, clion, coredump

I couldn't find anything on the web and seems like it can be done with Windows, but nothing for Linux.

I want to be able to open a core dump file and debug it (using its sources and binaries) using CLion's debugger, same as you can [debug with QtCreator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-operating-modes.html#launching-in-core-mode).
Is it possible? if not, does anyone know if they plan on adding this feature?

Comment: There's no such feature yet, unfortunately. Please upvote the corresponding issue on our tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-7977 GDB: Postmortem debug with a core file

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov, do I have to log in to upvote?

Comment: I'm not sure, probably you do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this is available now in CLion 2020.3.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/11/clion-2020-3-eap-core-dump/

Comment: And I only had to wait 4 years!